# How do i bind to all ip-address?

Tags: java, kubernetes, amazon-eks, ipv6, kubernetes-nodeport

I'm working on upgrading our eks cluster from 1.23 to 1.27. Some of the applications are failing because of the below error

```
Failed creating artifactory: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080
Failed creating archiva: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxx
  labels:
    app: abc
    heritage: "Tiller"
    chart: "jenkins-0.0.1"
    component: "jenkins-master"
  annotations:
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    component: "jenkins-master"
  type: NodePort
```

This error looks like its resolving to ipv6 loopback address, AWS docs mention that i should bind to all ipaddress , How do i do?
I tried disabling the ipv6 on the nodes, but i'm still getting the same error.

> Containerd has IPv6 enabled for Pods, by default. It applies node
> kernel settings to Pod network namespaces. Because of this, containers
> in a Pod bind to both IPv4 (127.0.0.1) and IPv6 (::1) loopback
> addresses. IPv6 is the default protocol for communication. Before
> updating your cluster to version 1.24, we recommend that you test your
> multi-container Pods. Modify apps so that they can bind to all IP
> addresses on loopback interfaces. The majority of libraries enable
> IPv6 binding, which is backward compatible with IPv4. When it’s not
> possible to modify your application code, you have two options:
>
> Run an init container and set disable ipv6 to true (sysctl -w
> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable ipv6=1).

Comment: I would assume they meanb the Unspecified address `::` for IPv6 or `0.0.0.0` for IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, by passing an env variable to use ipv4 address, What i understood is that, its detecting ipv6 from containerd because i believe ipv6 is default.
In jenkins used: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and also for all deployments, I could not find any other solution.

Made sure, our cni

```
   - name: ENABLE_IPv4
      value: "true"
    - name: ENABLE_IPv6
      value: "false"
```